# Package Utility doesn't exist error

Tags: java, package, utility

I'm trying the sourcecode from jLDADMM which is GibbsSamplingLDA.java, but i cannot compile it because i get this following error:

[image]

> package utility doesn't exist

maybe any of you ever experience the same problem? or maybe anyone know what is package utility and how to use it?

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it would be really helpful if you provide both the code and the screenshot of the error

Comment: i edited my question, i add a picture where the eror occurs. @johnII

Comment: if you downloaded everything then utility package should be included, you cannot just get GibbsSamplingLDA.java and use it by itself since it needs some classes in utility package

Comment: thank you so much, so helpfull. @johnII

Answer (score 0):

did you try with eclipse, This might works in eclipse. Wont compile on command line – says imported package does not exist:

Have two classes in two different packages (no inheritance)
class A SpecialDelivery – PKG = com.mgm2.specialdelivery
– Class B (UrgentMessage) has main() imports com.mgm2.specialdelivery.SpecialDelivery

c:\ src\com\mgm2 – has both specialdelivery and urgentmessage package paths -compile SpecialDelivery.java OK

Try to compile UrgentMessage from directory with both specialdelivery and urgentmessa pat h names so they are visible and get package specialdelivery does not exist.

To compile UrgentMessage.java use command
c:\src\com\mgm2 javac urgentmessage/UrgentMessage.java then it doesn’t reconize specialdelviery package even though I am compiling from the directory with both of them there.

Comment: I try it with netbeans